# Huge Gapping occured while visibility gone is done in adapter in order to filter according to the json response

Tags: android

I am using `Recylerview` adapter and `setVisibility`(View.Gone), also I have kept my XML file all `wrap_content`, still gapping is occurred.

```
if (chatHistory.getType().equals("request_sent")) {
        try {
            holder.requestsentAmount.setText("Requested: Rs." + chatHistory.getPaymentRequest().getRequestAmount());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.requestSentRemarks.setText("remarks:  " + chatHistory.getRemarks());
        holder.requestSentTime.setText(getDate(chatHistory.getTimestamp()));
    } else {

        holder.linearLayoutRequestSent.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    //filtering for paid data
    if (chatHistory.getType().equals("paid")) {

        holder.paidTime.setText(getDate(chatHistory.getTimestamp()));
        holder.paidRemarks.setText("remarks: " + chatHistory.getRemarks());
        try {
            holder.paidAmount.setText("Paid: Rs. " + chatHistory.getAmount());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {

        holder.linearLayoutPaid.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

Comment: post your full xml file which have linearLayoutRequestSent component

Comment: You need to provide more details, such your xml file, and a image showing what you're saying would be great.

Comment: My xml code consists simple Card view with height wrap_content.

Comment: @AndroidLearner if any privacy data is not there then please post it.. we can solve this easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **You just need to remove all margins from the `linearLayoutRequestSent` layout.**

Use padding instead of margin. Also if bottom margin or top margin is given in above/below component then remove it and add as padding inside `linearLayoutRequestSent`.

Also set it's visibility to gone in xml. and in java file in if condition set it visible and in else set gone

Comment: It didnt worked for me, also some of the data goes invisble while scrolling up and down.. :(

Comment: don't follow that last line it's ok.. your layout problem is solved? gap is now gone?

Comment: In question..just add it to question i will format it... by clicking on edit you can add in the question

Comment: or just copy paste here and share link in comment https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Thankyou  Vishva Dave, it worked for me keeping all Layout visibility gone in xml and view visible in adapter, also excluding margins, thankyou so much :) and how can i ask other question personally to you in stack overflow?

Comment: @AndroidLearner Happy to help :) happy coding :) And you can not ask question personaly to me but can notify me with comment :D

Comment: sure... expect more help from you guys :)

Comment: @Elisha yes please

Comment: Can you please suggest me the best library to show bar graph in android, you can provide me link here, i am having issues with MP chart. please please

Comment: @Elisha try https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-bar-chart-using-mpandroidchart-library-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks :) and how can we make screen size compatible according to different size mobile??

Comment: @Elisha don't know about screen sizes actually... but can try with different size layout files for that

Comment: Hello @Vishva Dave , can you please help me how to send image to server, like we send edittext by doing editext.getText, now can we do with imageview??

Comment: @Elisha hey try this tutorial : https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/08/upload-image-using-retrofit.html hope it helps..let me know if any problem in this

Comment: Hello @Vishva Dave. I am facing problem on uploading image, could you please help me?

Comment: @Elisha try that link demo and then try on actual one. it would work!

Comment: I worked fine, now please help me to plot graph according to json data in MP chart, i did sample graph.. but dont know how to plot with json data..

Comment: @Elisha in this demo link there is a arraylist which is shown in graph...just replace with your arraylist and keys ..you will get a chart according your json

Comment: Hello @Vishave Dave are you available there, need to ask a question.

Comment: @Elisha yes sure

Comment: I have used retrofit 2 and i get login access_token, it expires every 30 min, I have another api to refresh_token, i need to refresh token automatically in background. please help me to do this

Comment: @Elisha you can add count down timer which will run in background as well.

Comment: @Elisha I can't post full code here but you can check in so for count down timers if still any issue then can post a question

Comment: you can send me full code on elishadhunganaou@gmail.com , i will try it and discuss about issue here

Comment: @Elisha yes sent

Comment: genertateQrcode is my method which i am calling after 10 mins so you can call your refresh token there.. and instead 10 just do 30

Comment: And I have to pass token as authorization header to every api, how can I remove previous header and replace by new generated token automatically?

Comment: @Elisha you can try that with shared preferences.. may be by diting them

Comment: ,i need to show message when no item found in suggesion list of autocomplete textview, help me please.

Comment: you can try by manually adding one item in list when list is empty then can add item name as no results found and id to 0.. and disable click of id 0